# Multiple nested Iif and count statements in one cell

Tags: ms-access, count, iif

I have an example data in Access2010 .mdb as described below, the PipeId is the same for the three TVObservations. The FS, OB and RB describes the kind of observation, I need in to count the number of observations.

SampleData:

```
| PipeID | TVObservation | NumberOf |
|--------|---------------|----------|
|   301  |      FS       |    2     |
|   301  |      OB       |    2     |
|   301  |      RB       |    1     |
```

Needed output:

```
| PipeID |       NumberOf      |
|--------|---------------------|
|   301  | FS: 2, OB: 2, RB: 1 |
```

I can get the number of observations, but returning the observations with a Name/title before it, in one cell is proving difficult.

```
Count(Iif([TVObservation]="FS",True,IIf([TVObservation]="OB",True,IIf(TVObservation]="RB",True,Null)))) AS NumberOf
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but can you return AS within an Iif statement?
Like this perhaps:
      `Count(Iif([TVObservation]="FS" AS FS: ,True,IIf([TVObservation]="OB" AS OB:,True,IIf(TVObservation]="RB" AS RB:,True,Null)))) AS NumberOf`

Comment: I think you need to rephrase this.

Comment: MS Access doesn't have group concatenation function. check this link for allan browns solution. http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: You can also create a **crosstab query** with `TVObservation` as column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow-on from what @krish-km mentioned, here's a function I've adapted from [Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) (note that I've removed a lot of the original's general purpose utility, so should only be used for your specific scenario).

Put this in a VBA module...

```vb
Public Function ConcatRelated(strField1 As String, _
                strField2 As String, _
                strRelField As String, _
                lngRelFieldVal As Long, _
                strOrderBy As String, _
                strTable As String, _
                Optional strSeparator = ", ") As Variant

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim db As DAO.Database          ' Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset         '
    Dim strSql As String            ' SQL statement
    Dim strOut As String            ' Output string to concatenate to.
    Dim lngLen As Long              ' Length of string.

    ' Initialize to Null
    ConcatRelated = Null

    ' Find related records limited by related field
    strSql = "SELECT " & strRelField & ", " & strField1 & ", " & strField2 _
           & " FROM " & strTable & " WHERE " & strRelField & " = " & lngRelFieldVal _
           & " ORDER BY " & strOrderBy

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)

    ' Loop through related fields to build comma separated list
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        strOut = strOut & rs.Fields(strField1) & ": " & rs.Fields(strField2) & strSeparator
        rs.MoveNext        
    Loop

    rs.Close

    ' Return the string without the trailing separator.
    lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeparator)
    If _
        lngLen > 0 _
    Then
        ConcatRelated = Left(strOut, lngLen)
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    'Clean up
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ConcatRelated()"
    Resume Exit_Handler

End Function
```

You'll then be able to use this function in an SQL statement.

The first and second arguments are your 2 fields that you want to concatenate in to the comma-separated list; these are passed as strings so use double-quotes.

The third and forth argument is the the field whose value is the same across the records you're trying to summarise (in your case it's `PipeID`). Note that argument 3 needs to be in double-quotes `"PipeID"` and argument 4 is the sql-reference field, so mustn't be in quotes `tblTvObservations.PipeID`.

The fifth argument is the field you've specified in either `strField` or `strField2` that you want the comma separated list to be ordered by.

The sixth and final argument is the table/query name where this data comes from.

Here's an example of it used in an sql query...

```sql
SELECT tblTvObservations.PipeID, ConcatRelated("TVObservation","NumberOf","PipeID",tblTvObservations.PipeID,"TVObservation","tblTvObservations") AS NumberOf
FROM tblTvObservations;
```

...to get the following result:

[image]

Comment: Almost works, in NumberOf/Antalbemaerkning I seem to be getting all the TVObservations in one long list, instead of the ones applicable to the specific PipeID. I assume I’m doing something wrong. I forgot to mention that this concate is based on a query, don’t know if that has an effect?       



`SELECT Antal_Rorenestilstand.PipeID, ConcatRelated("TvObservation ", "NumberOf"," Antal_Rorenestilstand ") AS AntalBemaerkning
FROM Antal_Rorenestilstand
GROUP BY Antal_Rorenestilstand.LedningsID;`  



http://i.imgur.com/IFpCD8j.png?1

Comment: Shouldn't you group by `PipeID?` instead of `LedningsID`?

Comment: Oh yeah, it is grouped by PipeID, I'm translating from danish to english, just to give an idea about what the purpose of this is, missed that in my translation. `Antal_Rorenestilstand.PipeID, ConcatRelated("TvObservation ", "NumberOf"," Antal_Rorenestilstand ") AS AntalBemaerkning FROM Antal_Rorenestilstand GROUP BY Antal_Rorenestilstand.PipeID;`

Comment: Can you have more than 1 occurrence of the same `PipeID` & `TvObservation` in your data source?

Comment: Actually, I can see the problem.. I think the `.rs` needs to be limited to the `pipeID ` of the record it's currently looking at... I didn't see this problem because I only tested with one 1 `PipeID`.. give us a minute and I'll update my answer. I think it's just going to need another argument and a `WHERE` clause...

Comment: A PipeID can have several of the same types of TvObservation (RB, FS, IS etc.), but these would be located on different places on the pipe. 
This might not be the best way too show it, but can't think of a different way. First 5 different queries, 1 for RB, 1 for FS etc. http://i.imgur.com/LQNVQ9q.png these 5 are then joined in a Union http://i.imgur.com/KWTEVIt.png from this Union I count how many RB's and FS's etc there is for a given Pipe under Antal Observationer http://i.imgur.com/87hOilm.png and then I'm tring to concate that so I have those in one line. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The function has changed so paste this one in and re-read my notes as there's a few more arguments for the function.